# is there any form helpers for selecting time in hours minutes, and am pm in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, time-select

I have a time field in my database. I want to have a time select field to select the time as three drop downs, for a 12-hour clock. One drop down is to select the hours from 1 to 12, the second drop down is to select the minutes from 1 to 59, and the third drop down is to select the AM or PM, for a single time field column in database. I have searched for this kind of time helper, but I did't find one. Is there any way to customize the time select helper to select the time format in this way in Rails?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a built-in Rails helper that will add a separate select field for choosing between AM/PM. However, the `time_select` helper will allow you to select time in hours, minutes, AM/PM as you asked. This would most likely also be the suggested "Rails way" of accomplishing this. You can use the `:ampm` option to display hours as "12 PM", "01 AM", etc.

```
time_select 'game', 'game_time', {:ampm => true}
```

See the [`time_select` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_select) page for more info.

Comment: i want to take the three dropdowns  as i menctioned, and in controller can i construct a time object so that i can save this to  time field, by passing these strings(hours, minutes,am/pm) ?